# Wordpress Install: "ERROR: you must provide an e-mail address."

Tags: wordpress, installation, email-validation

Just trying to install Wordpress on a client server. Have installed Wordpress 20+ times before with no issues what so ever. However on this fresh install i am getting the following error when i try to progress from stage 1:

```
ERROR: you must provide an e-mail address.
```

(The first stage of the install, for anyone who isnt't aware, requires me to type in a name for the blog i am setting up and provide an email address for the new admin user account.)

I have double checked the password i am using, even tried numerous different email addresses, but i seem to be stuck on this screen which returns the above error.

I have double checked the requirements of the Wordpress install with the setup of the server and everything is fine there. I have also double checked the folder permissions of the folder where Wordpress has been uploaded to, and all appears fine there too.

If anyone has had this error before or has any suggestions for fixing it then i am all ears.

Thanks.

PS. Further inspection has shown that nothing is being passed through on the POST on this form.

```
array(0) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so i have managed to fix this issue.

All i did was take out two lines from inside my vhost file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
php_value post_max_size 16Ms
```

Im not sure why these would have effected POST on all forms i encountered on the Wordpress install but it resolved the issue and i have Wordpress up and running now.